# Closure on a Superset of the Rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, rational-numbers

I've been studying a specific super-set of the rationals that I've been trying to prove is not closed under addition.  The set is defined as all numbers of the form

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}{p_i^{\alpha_i}}
$$

where $p_i$ is the ith prime number and $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ (the exponents are rational) and the number of terms with non-zero alpha is finite.  I've been calling this set $\mathbb{S}$ because of their **s**emi-rational behavior, and the set is a **s**uper-set of the rationals.  It is easy to show that $\mathbb{S}$ is closed under multiplication and division.  What has been alluding me is a clear way to show that $\mathbb{S}$ is *not* closed under addition.  In fact, what I've been trying to prove is this:

> If $s$ and $t$ are numbers in $\mathbb{S}$, then $s+t\in\mathbb{S}$ if and only if $\frac{s}{t}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

I've tried going about it in similar ways of showing that radicals of products of distinct primes are irrational, but that's not quite enough to get the result.  I've also fiddled with some polynomial properties to no avail, and the efforts are dismal enough to not show so I don't confuse anyone...  If anyone could please give some advice/proof/counter-example, it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: *How* do you define addition at all for these forms of 'numbers'?

Comment: Perhaps I should state that $\mathbb{S}$ also includes $0$? Sorry for my lack of understanding, but are there multiple definitions of "addition"?

Comment: Is your products finite, (ie $\alpha_i$ is zero for large $i$ ) ?

Comment: @kelenner: yes, I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Note then that your set is $\{x>0; \exists d\in \mathbb{N}, d\geq 1, x^d\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: That is true and one of the reasons I tried going down polynomial routes, but I'm afraid my polynomial knowledge isn't very deep beyond the basics. Just seems like $x^d$ hints to polynomial.

Comment: I thought about the case when $\alhpa_n$ is not quasiconstant $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just display a case where closure fails.  We have $1,\sqrt 2\in \Bbb S$ but $1+\sqrt 2 \not \in \Bbb S$ because all the numbers in $\Bbb S$ have an integer power that is rational.

Comment: But can you _prove_ that $1+\sqrt{2}$  doesn't have an integer power that is rational?

Comment: Yes.  Just expand $(1+\sqrt 2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}1^k(\sqrt 2)^{n-k}$ by the binomial theorem.  All the terms with $n-k$ odd are integers times $\sqrt 2$ and are positive so they can't cancel.

Comment: And why can't $a+b\sqrt{2}$ have an integer power that is rational, where $a$ and $b$ are integers? This would need to be true for your binomial theorem statement to hold.  I think what you are getting at is that it can't have a integer power that is equal to 2.

Comment: The binomial is already of the form $a+b\sqrt 2$.  We just need that it is not rational, but $\sqrt 2$ is irrational and the rationals are closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Oh, alright, so $(1+\sqrt{2})^n=a+b\sqrt{2}$ which cannot be an integer. I hear yeah, great going. Thanks!