# How to show $a^{\frac{1}{b}}-c^{\frac{1}{d}}$ is rational if and only if $a^{\frac{1}{b}}$ and $c^{\frac{1}{d}}$ are rational and not equal.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, fractional-part

Given $a,d,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$, define

$$
X = a^\frac{1}{b}
$$
$$
Y = c^\frac{1}{d}
$$
$$
Z = X-Y
$$

I'm pretty sure the following is true:

> For any $X\neq Y$ that satisfy the above relationships, $Z$ is rational if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are rational.

I've been wanting to prove this relationship out of the interesting fact that it would show that if $X$ and $Y$ are irrational, then $\{X\}$ and $\{Y\}$ are unique, where $\{x\}$ represents the fractional part of a number, $x$. Or am I mistaken? Using the binomial theorem looks to be a good starting point, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660505/closure-on-a-superset-of-the-rationals) in an earlier post, but I've tried going from there and it seems to get murky, because you get alternating sequences of radicals.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit: The result of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669294/a-question-on-dense-subsets-of-the-0-1-interval-in-number-theory#2669322) question seems to show that this is in fact true.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: You need to make your statement more precise, because it is false as stated now : consider for example $a=3,b=2,c=9,d=4$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will update.

Comment: "For any X≠Y, Z is rational if and only if X and Y are rational" Hmmm... Try $X=1+\pi$ and $Y=\pi$.

Comment: $\pi$ cannot be represented as an integer raised to a unit fraction...

Comment: Yeah, we are slowly moving towards a sensible statement...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a hobbyist, not a professional. With every question, I learn something new.  I need to remember to be a precise as possible so I leave no holes.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: With "suitable" modifications (i.e., not as it is now), your statement is correct. However, I still do not see how the answer follows from the other thread.

Comment: I'm an optimist... :) @Paolo Leonetti: could you please make suitable modifications in an answer and show with such modifications it is true?  That would be great!

Comment: I am not posting this as an answer because it is a classical question. See this MSE question and reference therein: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150141/linear-independence-of-roots-over-q and also this article of Iure Boreico at p.87: http://www.math.harvard.edu/hcmr/issues/2.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good reading :)